# Fuzzy Images in Wordpress 4.4

Tags: images, responsive

I've got a problem with my site, newly uploaded images are uploading/displaying blurry. I think this has to do with the 4.4 update and responsive images... how can I fix this, or disable responsive images?

I've already tried the standard fixes such as altering image size, dimensions, "display full size", changing ppi, disabling all plugins, clearing my cache, etc, so I'm pretty sure it's a 4.4 problem. Here's [the page](http://www.classicingray.com/leather-bomber-new-balance-street-style/) that's displaying the blurry images, if that helps.

Comment: Images look fine from here (using Chrome)

Comment: They aren't horrible, but compared to the images on my computer they definitely look out of focus. I don't think it's just my browser because I've cleared cache & used incognito tab (also on chrome). My site is very photo-centric so I'd really like to get them looking crisp and in focus again.

Comment: @Scriptonomy This is the difference I'm seeing: http://s1075.photobucket.com/user/jlkclassic/media/blurred_zpsggf0rzy2.jpg.html

Answer (score 1):

The new responsive images feature takes some tweaking to make it work optimally. The standard settings work only for the most basic of themes.

[Read up on responsive images](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/), specifically the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes.

Manipulate the `srcset` and `sizes` values through the new [`wp_calculate_image_srcset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_calculate_image_srcset/) and  [`wp_calculate_image_sizes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_calculate_image_sizes/) filters.

There's also a [`max_srcset_image_width`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/max_srcset_image_width/) filter that allows you to override the maximum size that gets added to the `srcset`.

So depending on your theme you could try tweaking those values to get a result that always loads an appropriately sized image.

Answer (score 0):

## Image quality

When inserting images in posts, choose a higher resolution in the insert media dialogue. Also try to upload an image with the highest resolution possible.

## Compression

In Wordpress, images are resized and compressed when uploaded to media library. You can achieve higher quality images by manipulating the image compression settings.

Install this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplejpegquality/) to allow you to choose a different image compression setting. Once uploaded images are saved with the new JPEG compression setting. Note: That will not affect previously uploaded images.

Comment: I tried that plugin, uploaded a new photo... it helped a little bit but the photo still looks out of focus. Prior to today if I just uploaded a large file size, then selected "large" as the display size when creating a post they uploaded perfectly.